# Would char * xx[401] create 401 char pointers or a pointer to a char[401]?

Tags: c, pointers

I need to create a character double pointer that will have 401 character arrays.

Will `char *xx[401]` work, or will I have to use malloc and friends? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: Re "*Would char * xx[401] create 401 char pointers or a pointer to a char[401]?*", http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: It depends, if you want to fill those elements with string literals e.g. `xx[0] = "First"; xx[1] = "Second";` then you don't need to use `malloc`.

Comment: `char* xx [401]` -> array of character pointers. `char (*xx)[401]` -> pointer to array of 401 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
char *xx[401];
```

you are declaring an array of 401 **pointers to `char`**. All of them will need to be initialized to some other existing char array, for example in this way

```
char foo[20] = "Hello";
xx[107] = foo;
```

or `malloc`'ed, if they are intended to be a dynamically allocated array of strings.

If all these `malloc`s bother you, you can always define it statically

```
char xx[401][20+1] = { 0 };

/* Population of element at index 137 with a string defined somewhere else in the code: */
char str[] = "Hi guys";

strncpy(xx[123], str, 20);
```

(in this example every string will be of the fixed length of 20+1). But it will have to be a global variable: placing it in the stack wouldn't be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear you can rewrite this declaration

```
char *xx[401];
```

like

```
char * ( xx[401] );
```

That is it is an array with 401 elements of the type char *.

A pointer to this array will look like

```
char * ( *pxx )[401] = &xx;
```

Pointer to the element of the array will look like

```
char ** pxx = xx;
```

If you want to allocate dynamically an array with 401 elements of the type char * then the code can look like

```
char ** pxx = malloc( 401 * sizeof( char * ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how an array of pointers to character arrays can be dynamically allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 2, M = 6 };

    const char * hello[N] = { "Hello", "World" };

    char **s = malloc( N * sizeof( char * ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        s[i] = malloc( M );
        strcpy( s[i], hello[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i != 0 ) putchar( ' ' );
        printf( "%s", s[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        free( s[i] );
    }

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
```